# Electron desktop capturer undefined in the render process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm new to Electron and trying to follow the steps outlined in this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yqDxhR2XxE&t=442s&ab_channel=Fireship). My primary challenge appears to be encountering an `undefined` issue with the desktop capturer in the render process.

I understand that the video is old, and some features may not work exactly as described in the tutorial, such as enabling remote (which I'm also unsure if I fixed correctly) and context isolation. Currently, my files are structured as follows:

html.index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Electron Screen Recorder</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <script defer src="renderer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <h1>Electron Screen Recorder</h1>

    <video></video>

    <button id="startBtn" class="button is-primary">Start</button>
    <button id="stopBtn" class="button is-warning">Stop</button>

    <hr />

    <button id="videoSelectionBtn" class="button is_text">
      Choose a video source
    </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}

const createWindow = () => {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));

  // Open the DevTools.
  mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
};

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  /*
     It is common on OS X to create a new window in the app when the
     dock icon is clicked, especially if there are no other windows
     already open.
  */
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

 // In this file, you can incorporate the remaining components of your app's specific main process.
 // code. You can also put them in separate files and import them 
 here.
```

renderer.js

```
// buttons
const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');
const videoSelectionBtn = document.getElementById('videoSelectionBtn');

// imports
const { desktopCapturer } = require('electron');
// creating pop-menu
const { Menu } = require('@electron/remote/main').enable;


videoSelectionBtn.onclick= getVideoSrcs();


//Getting access to all available screens
async function getVideoSrcs(){
    // method returns promise 
    console.log(desktopCapturer);
    const inputSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
        types:['window', 'screen']
    });

    const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
        inputSources.map(source =>{
            return{
                label: source.name,
                click: () => selectSource(source)
            };
        })
    );
    console.log(inputSources);
    videoOptionsMenu.popup();
}
```

Then I get this:
[image]

I've attempted to find a solution online, but all I've come across suggests that I need to run the capturer in the render process. However, I believed I was already doing that. I also tried preloading and consulted the documentation, but it didn't resolve the issue and introduced additional errors, indicating that I must have overlooked something. My anticipated outcome was to have a popup dropdown menu similar to this appear upon clicking the button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[The document](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/desktop-capturer) says that you can access the desktop capturer module in the main process only, a IPC call to main process probably solves your problem,

Comment: oh i see should i should be using that import at least in the main. but you suggest using ipc call to main should solve it ,but how does that look like. the link you posted just shows it in the preload